# What is the best way to manage permission with ACL in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony

I'm working in a project using Symphony 2. It is complex project and requires a lot security elements. I'm trying to create ACL to give or to revoke permission to the user but I have a problem: I don't know how I can obtain the permissions for a user. I need a best way to manage ACL permissions.

I need the permission level from modules to fields in the database and retrieve this permissions in the security module.

Now I have the system in 2 different databases and on one database I can't change anything, the other database contains all of my security tables and other things but I need to give permissions in those databases.

I was thinking of creating an external interface to manage the ACL but this would be the same as creating a replicate Symphony 2 ACL.

What is the best way to permissions management in the System using Symphony 2?

And

How I can check the permission to the field in the entity because the method isGranted in twig I think isn't the best way because it would query database for every field?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set roles to users, it is all described here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles

Once your roles are defined, you can use them in your access control list, or in any controller/template with the isGranted method. This is a SF2 best practice, and as far as I know there is no performance issue with the isGranted method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with multiple way, inside an action in a controller:

```
public function helloAction($name)
{
    if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Inside Twig:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    <a href="...">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
```